# Installing and using Emscripten

Tags: java, ubuntu, path, installation, emscripten

I installed Emscripten through the steps shown below:

```
1.) Download the emsdk-portable version for Linux/MacOSX
http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/downloads.html#sdk-downloads
2.)
Run
$ ./emsdk update
$ ./emsdk install latest
$ ./emsdk activate latest
$ source emsdk_env.sh (To update your environment variables)
```

I  believe everything installed correctly, however I am unable to run emscripten anywhere outside of the emsdk folder.

I need to be able to run em++ in my: Documents/project3/dataviz/graphiti folder.

Also, when I run ***em++ -v*** in my emsdk folder, I get the following message I have been unable to resolve:

```
Java does not seem to exist, requierd for closure compiler,
which is optional (define JAVA in /home/bryce/.emscripten if you want it)
```

I attempted to define the java path in the folder, but I'm not sure how it should look.

Any help resolving these two issues would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem sounds like the `PATH` isn't being set correctly. Type `echo $PATH` after running `source emdsk_env.sh` and check that the path to your emscripten installation has been added.

Note that you have to export the `PATH` for each terminal session you're using (it might be an idea to put `source <path to emsdk dir>/emsdk_env.sh` in your `.bashrc` file so this gets done automatically).

Could this link help with the second problem?

https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/building_from_source/verify_emscripten_environment.html#installing-missing-components

Comment: Sorry, dumb followup question. In where should I put that source line in .bashrc? I don't want to mess anything up

Comment: just put it at the bottom of the file. It shouldn't mess anything up, but if it does as long as you remove the line everything should go back to normal in any new terminal session ;)

Comment: that worked! For anyone else looking at this question I resolved the java bit through Johns link, but had to a bit deeper to here: https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/building_from_source/index.html#installing-from-source